# Tensorflow - Memory management on GeForce 970 with im2txt

Tags: python, ubuntu, tensorflow, deep-learning

I just wanted to know if there is a way to avoid im2txt to use the superslow 0.5GB of the GeForce 970 GTX. Can we force a training session to use only the regular 3,5GB ? Is it a good idea ?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can select the specific GPU memory to use.  Seems that the 970 has some issues with that memory partition. You can disable the use of GPUs.

Comment: Disabling the GPU for a deeplearning serious application is just a non sense.

Comment: Using the GeForce 970 for serious application is just non sense. Is a (buggy) gaming card. Get your money back: http://www.pcgamer.com/heres-how-to-claim-your-30-nvidia-geforce-gtx-970-settlement/

Comment: No it's not. It's still really faster than any CPU, even with the memory bug that drop it down to the level of a 580. And for my money, I'm trying -_- not that easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to limit the total amount of memory using command below. Not sure which memory that allocates though, it could include the slow 0.5GB if you are unlucky

```
gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.7)
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options))
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that as soon as I'm home.

Comment: @MathieuArbezHermoso Can you please share the result?